# Decrypting javascript encrypted password on client side

Tags: javascript, forms, http, encryption, passwords

I am currently attempting to develop a quick tool that would allow me to check my cellular plan balance (carrier being MetroPCS). To do this, I need to be able to login to the metro website with a library (like python requests) that does not render javascript. While checking the post request for the login form on metro's website, I noticed that the password field (labeled "verificationValue") seems to be encrypted. This obviously means I cannot login with a plain text password. [Encrypted pin number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFGN6.png)

I have attempted to look up ways to somehow trace back the javascript that may handle encrypting the password field before it is sent as a post request but was unable to find anything that I could understand.

Comment: To be honest I think you are doing this at the wrong layer. It would make far more sense to extract such data using something like puppeteer (remote control a real browser instance on the server side) so you can completely decouple from the sites implementation details. Even if you manage to reverse engineer it, it will be fragile to changes on the site, whereas automating a browser on the serverside would not be as fragile.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to find a way to interact with the service directly, bypassing the login form. For example, you might be able to use an API provided by the service to check your balance, rather than logging in to the website